# strings.Split golang

Tags: golang, текст

Возникла задача разбить файл `.txt` на отдельные элементы.
Для лучшего понимания скрин:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался парсить через функцию `strings.Split` , не получается так как делимитер в роли пустой строки не подходит ибо размер пустой строки всегда разный.
На выходе хотелось бы получить 1 строка = 1 array. Пишу на `php` с `golang` на любительском уровне. Если есть какие нибудь соображения буду рад услышать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам может помочь
[`strings.Fields`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Fields):

> Fields splits the string s around each instance of one or more
> consecutive white space characters, as defined by unicode.IsSpace,
> returning a slice of substrings of s or an empty slice if s contains
> only white space.

Там же
[пример](https://play.golang.org/p/i_3x-wRvAxx):

```golang
fmt.Printf("Fields are: %q", strings.Fields("  foo bar  baz   "))
// Output:
//   Fields are: ["foo" "bar" "baz"]
```

Comment: Спасибо)its work